# How to design thin scrollbar in extJS 3.4 like facebook provides for lists & chat

Tags: facebook, html, extjs, css

Friends i want to know is there any plugin or sample example to do thin scrollbar like facebook provides for lists & chat

Comment: just an idea - you could check the source code of the extjs documentation. It also have thin scroll bars, and it is extjs.

Comment: @innerJL i know it is possible in 4.0 ExtJS but as it is MVC & i am currently using 3.4 so its providing regular scrollbar .
Can you tell if i can customize it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know exactly how to do this. But I see that sencha already did this in their docs. And it doesn't matter ExtJs4 or 3 it is. The approach should be the same. Look into the source code :)

Comment: Can you add the code of what you have tried so far? And I'd remove the facebook tag, as this is nothing to do with facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a list of 10 scrollbars that would be suitable:

http://www.net-kit.com/jquery-custom-scrollbar-plugins/

Comment: Why would he accept an answer that does not even relate to his question... he's asking about ExtJS plugins and you reply with jQuery plugins...